# Data automatically getting published in sanity

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, save, sanity

I am creating a client instance using the sanity client in react js app, but the entry is getting automatically published, which I don't want. Is there any way to avoid publishing and save the data to the schema, so I can manually publish it later ?? I tried draft=true way, didn't worked

```
client
      .create(entry, { publish: false })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("success");
        setLoading(false);
        setIsFormSubmitted(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

**Please let me know if anyone knows the solution**